# PrimaVera p6 to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, primavera

I would like to know if there is a way through which I can connect Prima Vera P6 with powerBI in a way that whenever I make a change in Prima Vera P6 it automatically reflects in PowerBI, can I make a live connection?

My company already has a system through which Data is converted into excel files and then dashboards are created on PowerBi But they want to make a live connection

Comment: How are they converting the data to Excel? What is the backend datasource for Primavera P6? If it is SQL database, then you should be able to connect to the DB directly and hopefully with DirectQuery.